# SQL CROSS APPLY with TOP

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm on SQL Server 2008/2012. I have a tallytable in `#MonthTally`

```
;WITH
  Pass0 AS (SELECT 1 AS C UNION all SELECT 1), --2 rows
  Pass1 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM Pass0 AS A, Pass0 AS B),--4 rows
  Pass2 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM Pass1 AS A, Pass1 AS B),--16 rows
  Pass3 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM Pass2 AS A, Pass2 AS B),--256 rows
  Tally AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY C) AS N FROM Pass3)
SELECT TOP 256 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS N
INTO #MonthTally
FROM Tally
ORDER BY N
```

I'm using the tallytable like this

```
-- Insert 5 future years
SELECT TOP(5) V.CompanyId, V.StartDate, V.EndDate
FROM #MonthTally T
CROSS APPLY
(   
SELECT
    F.CompanyId,
    DATEADD(YY, T.N,MAX(F.StartDate)) AS StartDate,
    DATEADD(YY, T.N,MAX(F.EndDate)) AS EndDate
    FROM FiscalPeriods F
    GROUP BY CompanyId  
) V
```

I have read that whenever you use TOP you should always use ORDER BY to ensure what TOP returns. So I can't count on `SELECT TOP(5) * FROM #MonthTally` to always return 1 through 5 unless I use a ORDER BY, regardless of how data was inserted into `#MonthTally`. But how do I get a ORDER BY on my CROSS APPLY.

Its not worse then I can aggregate outside the CROSS APPLY. Its probably bad performance to GROUP BY each line anyway. But I would like to know regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I would just use `WHERE N BETWEEN 1 AND 5`.

In general though you can put the query into a CTE or subquery that uses `TOP`

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT TOP(5) N
FROM #MonthTally
ORDER BY N
)
SELECT V.CompanyId, V.StartDate, V.EndDate
FROM T
CROSS APPLY
(   
SELECT
    F.CompanyId,
    DATEADD(YY, T.N,MAX(F.StartDate)) AS StartDate,
    DATEADD(YY, T.N,MAX(F.EndDate)) AS EndDate
    FROM FiscalPeriods F
    GROUP BY CompanyId  
) V
ORDER BY T.N
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the BETWEEN 1 AND 5.